# How to eliminate a Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

email.comusing this html code:

```
    <form id="emailform" name="emailform" method="post" action="" >     
       <label>Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" />

       <label >Email</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" />

       <label >Message</label>
       <textarea name="message"></textarea>

       <div id="errormessage"></div>

       <input type="submit" value="send" class="button" />
       <input id="hiddenID" type="reset" name="hidden" />
</form>
```

with this script:

```
$("#emailform").submit(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "email.ajax.php",
                        data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
                        dataType: "json",

                        success: function(msg){
                            $("#errormessage").removeClass('error');
                            $("#errormessage").addClass(msg.status);
                            $("#errormessage").html(msg.message);
                            $("#hiddenID").click();

                        },
                        error: function(){
                            $("#errormessage").removeClass('success');
                            $("#errormessage").addClass('error');
                            $("#errormessage").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

and this php:

```
<?php

function checkEmail($email){

        if(eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]", $email)){
    return FALSE;
}

list($Username, $Domain) = split("@",$email);

if(@getmxrr($Domain, $MXHost)){
    return TRUE;

} else {
    if(@fsockopen($Domain, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30)){
        return TRUE; 
    } else {

        return FALSE; 
    }
}
}   


$response_array = array();

if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'Name is blank';
} elseif(!checkEmail($_POST['email'])) {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'Email is blank or invalid';
} elseif(empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    $response_array['message'] = 'Message is blank';
} else {
    $body = $_POST['name'] . " sent you a message\n";
    $body .= "Details:\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    mail("email@email.com", "Portfolio", $body);

    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    $response_array['message'] = 'Email sent!';

}


echo json_encode($response_array);

?>
```

I'm getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null" error at success msg and cant seem to figure why.  It catches the name error but then doesnt like the email validation.  Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you're on PHP 5.2+ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line creating the error: `$("#errormessage").addClass(msg.status);`

You are trying to access the `status` property of the `msg` object and the error is telling you that `msg` is either not an object or it has no property named `status`.

Do a `console.log(msg);` on the first line of your callback function to see what is actually being returned to the JavaScript.

Comment: its returning null, I dont understand why.

Comment: It would seem as though your PHP script isn't outputting anything. Try debugging it by letting the form submit normally and do a whole-page-refresh, you should then be able to see the PHP error(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your echo:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response_array);
```